# How to remove double parentheses using subfig/subfloat?

Tags: subfloats, subfig

What is causing and how to remove the double parenthesis in the example below?

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \begin{center}
    \subfloat[Bebê chorando]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{baby}}
    \subfloat[Voz de adulto]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{adult}}\\
    \subfloat[Ronco]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{snoring}}
    \subfloat[Chuva]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{rain}}\\
    \subfloat[Som externo]{\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{street}}
    \caption{Exemplares de espectrogramas gerados.}
    \label{fig:espectrogramas}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Please give a minimal working sample!

Comment: @Kuttens, what do you need?

Comment: Code for a complete but small document we can copy-paste-compile to get the double-bracket problem ourselves.

Comment: Note that 'parentheses' are (also) 'brackets' in UK English. To distinguish, we'd say 'round brackets' or 'square brackets' or 'curly brackets'. So just saying 'double brackets' won't necessarily be clear to people on this side of the Atlantic.

Comment: A [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) is a little but complete, compilable document, which reproduces your problem, without it it is impossible to answer.

Comment: I only get double parentheses if I add `\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{(\alph{subfigure})}` to the document preamble. If you have something like that, remove it. Also use `\centering` in place of `\begin{center}` (and remove `\end{center}`).

Answer (score 2):

I had this issues as well,  I was trying to use subfigure, but I was having issues. The package subfigure has been deprecated and is considered obsolete. I switch to subfig and my code had both:

\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subfig}

Comment out subfigure and try again, it fixed the issues for me.